# Can't update all variables from function

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my JS:

```
var money = 4;
var thirst = 50;
function satisfy(what,how,price,sBar){
    if(price<=money){
        what=what+how;
        money=money-price;
        updateBar(sBar,what);
        updateMoney();
    } else {
        log.unshift("D"+day+" "+hour+":"+minute+" - Poor hobo, you don't have enough money for that. <br>");
        updateLog();
    };
};
```

And this is in my html

```
<a onClick="satisfy(thirst,30,0.84,'#thirst')";>buy</a>
```

After I click it problem is that global variable for `thirst` doesn't get updated but `money` global variable does get updated. How can I fix it to make `thirst` global variable updated too?

Thank you, very much.

Comment: IF you want to use `what`, somewhere you need `thirst = what;` I suggest `thirst=thirst+how;`, having thirst as the parameter variable name.

Comment: There is no code that does anything with the thirst variable?

Comment: `thirst` doesn't get updated because your code doesn't update it.

Comment: The "thirst" variable modified in the method is the local one not the global one

Comment: But 'what' is not only used for 'thirst', it's also used for 'hunger'.

Comment: @Kyrbi, then you have to show us more code. Can you not call thirst and huger "what" instead?

Comment: For example there is also <a onClick="satisfy(hunger,30,0.84,'#hunger')";>buy</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because JavaScript numbers are passed by **value**, not by **reference**, meaning that a copy of `thirst` is created and modified. Why not return a value instead:

HTML:

```
<a id="buy-link">buy</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var money = 4;
var thirst = 50;

function satisfy(what, how, price, sBar) {
    if (price <= money){
        what += how;
        money -= price;
        updateBar(sBar,what);
        updateMoney();
    } else {
        log.unshift("D" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + " - Poor hobo, you don't have enough money for that. <br>");
        updateLog();
    }

    return what;
}

var buyLink = document.getElementById("buy-link");
buyLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
    thirst = satisfy(thirst, 30, 0.84, '#thirst')
}, false);
```

I also removed some of your unneeded semicolons, converted your event handler into using the standard [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) function, and cleaned up your code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely had to "pass by reference" you could pass an object then modify the contents inside the function.

```
var money = 4,
    thirst = 50,
    myObj = {
      what: 'thirst',
      how: 30,
      price: 0.84,
      sBar: '#thirst'
    }

function doSomething(obj) {
   obj.what = 'hunger';
   obj.how = 20;
}

doSomething(myObj);
console.log(myObj.what); // "hunger"
```

Answer (score 0):

add

thirst=what;

after:

```
updateMoney();
```

however, since you're using it as a parameter, I suspect you're planning to pass different variables besides "thirst" to the function

in that case, just pass a string, like "thirst".   then in your function have something like

```
if (what=="thirst")
      thirst=what;
if (what=="hunger")
      hunger= what;
```

etc

Comment: Well then, what if I want to update 'hunger', with <a onClick="satisfy(hunger,30,0.84,'#hunger')";>buy</a>?